Projective cover of simple module is unique up to scalar multiple
In the proof of $\dim_K Hom_A(P,M) = [M : S]$ where $P \twoheadrightarrow S$ is a projective cover and $S$ is simple (right) $A$-module, I am stuck at the following. ($A$ is finite dimensional $K$-algebra where $K$ is algebraically closed, as usual)
$$Hom_A(P, S) \simeq K$$
That is, the nonzero map $P \to S$ is determined up to $K$-multiple.
Why does this hold?
Does this imply $End_A P \simeq K$ as well, considering uniqueness of projective cover up to isomorphism?

Looks like there's a missing assumption - K should be an algebraically closed field.

Yeah, missed that. Sorry.

In general (i.e. not assuming algebraically closed) we have $\text{Hom}_A(P,S) \cong \text{End}_A(S)$ as $K$-vector spaces. See Proposition 8.3 in this very nice note by Tom Leinster. The key fact is that $P$ has a unique maximal submodule, hence all surjections $P \to S$ factor through one another.
Also $\text{End}_A(P) \not\cong K$ in general. For example, look at $A = K[x]/(x^n)$, where $n \ge 2$. There is a unique simple module $S$ (which is one-dimensional), and its projective cover is $P = A$. In this case we have $\text{End}_A(P) \cong A$, which is $n$-dimensional.
